# How do I handle rumors about myself that I started?

Tags: politics

So more than two years ago I revealed a vulnerable detail(something I thought I had done wrong) about how I got hired, to one or two people. One of those who heard my 'story' were doubtful that whatever happened was actually problematic. What he said was, "if HR hired me without making a fuss about my 'mistake', why bother talking about it now"?

Why did I say bad things about myself? It was a form of self-sabotage that came from feeling confident that I could live free of the rungs of office politics, yet feeling undeserved at the same time because I could not escape its effects.

Later on I found out that what I had done was not wrong, at least legally. The issue about my hire, though, is reminiscent of sensitive office politics, about previous company leadership and current leadership being in a conflict, and so forth.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/articles/200811/the-8-laws-rumor-spread

According to this post, it says "The more you hear a rumor, the more you'll buy it, even if you're hearing that it's false".

Does my case fall into this scenario, where I'm better off not even denying or correcting myself? I sometimes hear that people don't really care all that much about me so I better not be so paranoid; am I really paranoid?

Comment: You said something two years ago and you still hear it repeated in the hallways?

Comment: I'm afraid people will be talking about the issue behind my back, but I don't actually hear it or get hinted at it on a daily basis.

Comment: There is no rumor.  There is a comment you made two years ago, to which one person at the time said "ignore it and move on".  What do you think you need to handle?

Answer (score 2):

Based on comment it seems that you're suffering from the problem that is more commonly known as:

**It's in your head, let it go.**

It is common for people to exaggerate their problems, and think them over and over, that's why most likely nobody remembers what you said two years ago - they're preoccupied with what other people (you?) think about what they said and did.

We all make mistakes, don't dwell on them too long because it will prevent you from focusing on future.

Comment: You beat me to the obvious answer. OP, be aware that unless you actually (over)hear the rumour, you can't confirm if it is still active without asking - and that would only make it active again, even if it were not. Do as Drakemor says and let it go - your colleagues have